# Definition of subgroup generated by a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Yes, I've checked the other similarly titled questions (they seem more on par with abstract algebra for a grad level course).  From the Gilbert and Gilbert text we have the following definition

$$\langle A\rangle =\{x\in G| x=a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n, \quad a_i\in A\quad or \quad -a_i\in A\}$$

for an arbitrary $A$ which is a subset of the group $G$.  I don't like this definition because it doesn't seem natural; specifically the $n$ is fixed (and comes from apparently nowhere).  An exercise I'm currently working on is to show that if $H_1,H_2,\ldots H_n$ are subgroups of an abelian group $G$, then $G=H_1+H_2+\cdots + H_n$ if and only if $G$ is generated by $\bigcup_{j=1}^n H_j$.

I don't want help with this second problem; however, I'm sharing it in hopes that it will clarify why I'm confused.  From the definition of $\langle A \rangle $ it seems that $n$ is arbitrary, that is to say it doesn't "know" that $H$ is the sum of $n$ distinct subgroups.  But if that's the case then when trying to the prove the second problem I don't know how to get started because I write something like the following:

If $g\in G$ (and $G$ is generated by the union) then $g=a_1+\cdots + a_k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and each $a_i\in \bigcup_{j=1}^n H_j$.  I suppose I'm doing this correctly, I just don't trust this definition -- how does $\langle A \rangle $ know to "go up to" $n$?

Comment: You're right that the $n$ in the definition of $<A>$ is arbitrary. It's fixed in the second part of the question. Consider thinking of the definition of $<A>$ as containing those elements $x$ that "for some $m$ are the sum of $m$ elements ..."

Comment: The way I am interpreting the definition is " $\langle A\rangle$ consists of the elements in $G$ that can be expressed as a linear combination of the ones in $A$. " I don't think the $n$'s are related from your first and second questions (as you already figured out and has already been pointed out by Matt and Ethan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an odd definition, but it's correct as long as $n$ is *not* fixed. $n$ must be allowed to be any positive integer or else $\{1\}$ does not generate $\Bbb Z$ (which it does).

Comment: Righto.... yeah, just in the book it seems that $n$ is fixed because of the unusual juxtaposition.  This is how it is written in the book: [centered equation above follow  by] "It is left as an exercise to prove that if $H_1,H_2,\ldots, H_n$ are subgroups of an abelian group $G$ then $G=H_1+H_2+\cdots H_n$ if and only if $G$ is generated by $\bigcup_{j=1}^n H_j$."

I guess it appeared fixed given the exercise that $immediately$ followed it.  Poor wording.

Thank you for you clarification!

Comment: @Clcl No problem.